# make jquery default collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have phpbb 3.1 forum.
i have a- jquery.collapse.js.
i want that the defult will be collapsed insted of open.
wheat parameter do i need to change to do it?
and can o make it that in default only 1 is open and not close?
the default will be the 1st category to be open, and when i open the next one, the open one will close automatically.

the code-

```js
(function($, exports) {

  // Constructor
  function Collapse (el, options) {
    options = options || {};
    var _this = this,
      query = options.query || "> :even";

    $.extend(_this, {
      $el: el,
      options : options,
      sections: [],
      isAccordion : options.accordion || false,
      db : options.persist ? jQueryCollapseStorage(el.get(0).id) : false
    });

    // Figure out what sections are open if storage is used
    _this.states = _this.db ? _this.db.read() : [];

    // For every pair of elements in given
    // element, create a section
    _this.$el.find(query).each(function() {
      new jQueryCollapseSection($(this), _this);
    });

    // Capute ALL the clicks!
    (function(scope) {
      _this.$el.on("click", "[data-collapse-summary] " + (scope.options.clickQuery || ""),
        $.proxy(_this.handleClick, scope));

      _this.$el.bind("toggle close open",
        $.proxy(_this.handleEvent, scope));

    }(_this));
  }

  Collapse.prototype = {
    handleClick: function(e, state) {
      e.preventDefault();
      state = state || "toggle";
      var sections = this.sections,
        l = sections.length;
      while(l--) {
        if($.contains(sections[l].$summary[0], e.target)) {
          sections[l][state]();
          break;
        }
      }
    },
    handleEvent: function(e) {
      if(e.target == this.$el.get(0)) return this[e.type]();
      this.handleClick(e, e.type);
    },
    open: function(eq) {
      this._change("open", eq);
    },
    close: function(eq) {
      this._change("close", eq);
    },
    toggle: function(eq) {
      this._change("toggle", eq);
    },
    _change: function(action, eq) {
      if(isFinite(eq)) return this.sections[eq][action]();
      $.each(this.sections, function(i, section) {
        section[action]();
      });
    }
  };

  // Section constructor
  function Section($el, parent) {

    if(!parent.options.clickQuery) $el.wrapInner('<a href="#"/>');

    $.extend(this, {
      isOpen : false,
      $summary : $el.attr("data-collapse-summary",""),
      $details : $el.next(),
      options: parent.options,
      parent: parent
    });
    parent.sections.push(this);

    // Check current state of section
    var state = parent.states[this._index()];

    if(state === 0) {
      this.close(true);
    }
    else if(this.$summary.is(".open") || state === 1) {
      this.open(true);
    } else {
      this.close(true);
    }
  }

  Section.prototype = {
    toggle : function() {
      this.isOpen ? this.close() : this.open();
    },
    close: function(bypass) {
      this._changeState("close", bypass);
    },
    open: function(bypass) {
      var _this = this;
      if(_this.options.accordion && !bypass) {
        $.each(_this.parent.sections, function(i, section) {
          section.close();
        });
      }
      _this._changeState("open", bypass);
    },
    _index: function() {
      return $.inArray(this, this.parent.sections);
    },
    _changeState: function(state, bypass) {

      var _this = this;
      _this.isOpen = state == "open";
      if($.isFunction(_this.options[state]) && !bypass) {
        _this.options[state].apply(_this.$details);
      } else {
        _this.$details[_this.isOpen ? "show" : "hide"]();
      }

      _this.$summary.toggleClass("open", state !== "close");
      _this.$details.attr("aria-hidden", state === "close");
      _this.$summary.attr("aria-expanded", state === "open");
      _this.$summary.trigger(state === "open" ? "opened" : "closed", _this);
      if(_this.parent.db) {
        _this.parent.db.write(_this._index(), _this.isOpen);
      }
    }
  };

  // Expose in jQuery API
  $.fn.extend({
    collapse: function(options, scan) {
      var nodes = (scan) ? $("body").find("[data-collapse]") : $(this);
      return nodes.each(function() {
        var settings = (scan) ? {} : options,
          values = $(this).attr("data-collapse") || "";
        $.each(values.split(" "), function(i,v) {
          if(v) settings[v] = true;
        });
        new Collapse($(this), settings);
      });
    }
  });

  //jQuery DOM Ready
  $(function() {
    $.fn.collapse(false, true);
  });

  // Expose constructor to
  // global namespace
  exports.jQueryCollapse = Collapse;
  exports.jQueryCollapseSection = Section;

})(window.jQuery, window);
```

the forum- limodim.com/1
thank you.